# How to disable "Project Files Changes" alert in phpstorm?

Tags: phpstorm

**How to disable this alert box in phpstorm.**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the way you can avoid "Project Files Changed" alerts

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-1417#comment=27-144693